# Generate all possible permutations for 'n' boolean elements that have at most 'm' elements that are 1 or True

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I want to generate a full list of permutations of 4 elements that have at most two '1'.

For example I have n= 4 and m = 2:

I want all the permutations that have at most two '1' in it:

[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],
 [1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,1], [1,1,0,0], [1,1,0,0], [1,0,0,1]... you get the idea.

I tried to generate a full list of all the permutations and then doing If SUM < 3 then give it to me. It worked well when the n was small. The problem is that I need to do it for big n>30 .

As you can see the iterations will go to 2^N and it will not be feasible.

As m is smaller (I work with m smaller than 5), I just need a small percentage of permutations compared to all the possible combinations.
And the order of magnitude for the iterations becomes N^M so it will be N^5 in this case.

Is there a easy way to generate this list??

[Edited: wrote at least instead of at most]

Comment: At least or at most !!

Comment: You wrote "at least two 1" in the first sentence, and "at most two 1" in the next. Please clarify what exactly you need.

Comment: Yes, it is at most sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of permutations of a boolean array of length `n` with exactly `m` true values is essentially the same as the set of `m`-combinations of the a set of `n` things, which is what is returned by `itertools.combinations`. (The `n` things, in this case, are the indices of the `m` true values.)

To get the permutations of *up to* `m` true values, we just have to chain together the combinations of `i` values for `i` in `range(m + 1)`, which can easily be done with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
# This returns an iterator
up_to_m_of_n = lambda n, m: chain.from_iterable(combinations(range(n), i)
                                                for i in range(m+1))
# Example:
list(up_to_m_of_n(4, 2))
[(), (0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Turning those index arrays into a boolean array is a little annoying but still doable:

```
from operator import setitem
from functools import reduce
up_to_m_of_n_true = lambda n, m: map(lambda inds: reduce(lambda a, ind: setitem(a, ind, True) or a,
                                                         inds, [False] * n),
                                     up_to_m_of_n(n, m))
# Example (output reformatted)
list(up_to_m_of_n_true(4,2))
[False, False, False, False]
[True, False, False, False]
[False, True, False, False]
[False, False, True, False]
[False, False, False, True]
[True, True, False, False]
[True, False, True, False]
[True, False, False, True]
[False, True, True, False]
[False, True, False, True]
[False, False, True, True]
```

Note that unlike your example, this includes the case where there are no True values.

The perhaps overly-functional up_to_m_of_n_true might be more readable as:

```
def indices_to_boolean(n, inds):
  bools = [False] * n
  for ind in inds: bools[ind] = True
  return bools

def up_to_m_of_n_true(n, m):
  for inds in up_to_m_of_n(n, m):
    yield indices_to_boolean(inds, n)
```

Comment: Ah! this is actually very smart. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

l = list(permutations([0, 0, 1, 1]))
```

if you only need the unique ones you can wrap it in a `set`:

```
set(list(permutations([0, 0, 1, 1])))
```

if **counting the number** of such permutations / combinations is your only concern and you don't need to use actual instances of the permutations in your data, just use math. There are closed-form expressions for all of that stuff, see combinatorics.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this meets your performance expectations, here's one approach:

**Description:**

1. `n` is the uniform length of the binary sequences that we are going to generate (eg, 5).`max_ones` is the maximum number of ones (eg, 3)
2. `ones`, is the number of ones in one of the valid permutations. It can vary from from 0 to `max_ones`.
3. For each such valid value of `ones` (say `ones == 3`), the permutations are obtained by taking a "seed" (say `(1,1,1,0,0)`), making an iterator that generates permutations of that "seed" sequence, and finally, passing that iterator to `set()` (so it automatically avoids duplicates). The expression `(1,)*ones + (0,)*(n-ones)` creates the "seed" sequence.
4. As 'ones' varies from 0 to `max_ones`, we will get many such sets. We finally `chain()` all of these sets together.

**Code:**

```
import itertools as itr

n = 4
max_ones = 2

my_all_atmost = set(itr.chain.from_iterable([set(itr.permutations(seed_row)) 
                                             for seed_row in {(1,)*ones + (0,)*(n-ones) 
                                                              for ones in range(0,max_ones+1)}]))
```

**Output: (For the example where `n == 4, max_ones == 2)`:**

```
print (my_all_atmost)
{(1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0), 
(0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), 
(0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), 
(0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)}
```